# 404 when adding params to Express route

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to pass a url param like

> http://xxx/api/users?facebookUserId=10213594301678639

Here is my App.js:

```
// route setup
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/api/users', usersRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

and here is my users.js:

```
router.get('/:facebookUserId', jsonParser, async (req, res) => {
  // get user by facebookUserId
  const users = db.collection('users');  
  const facebookUserId = req.params.facebookUserId; 
  const query = {
    facebookUserId: facebookUserId,
  };
  const user = await findOne(users, query);
  res.json(user);
});

module.exports = router;
```

My problem is that I get 404 as soon as I add

> :facebookUserId

to router.get()

Comment: facebookUserId in your example url is not a url param. It’s a query param. https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query

Comment: thats because if you see you have defined route as `/api/users/?facebookUserId=10213594301678639` but actually you are making request to `/api/users?facebookUserId=10213594301678639` notice the extra `/`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky doing the following to capture query param works:

```router.get(':facebookUserId?' ... (req, res) => {
  ...
  const facebookUserId = req.query.facebookUserId; 
  ...
});```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your route you're expecting the parameter `facebookUserId` to be a route-parameter (like /api/users/10213594301678639) but in the example above you're calling the route with a query-parameter (/api/users?facebookUserId=10213594301678639)

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're trying to get the query string not the param from the get endpoint route.

In your **users.js**, get the query string from `req.query`

```
// as your path is the same with the endpoint prefix api/users, use '/'
router.get('/', jsonParser, async (req, res) => {
  // get user by facebookUserId
  const users = db.collection('users');  

  // get the query string from req.query
  const facebookUserId = req.query.facebookUserId; 

  const query = {
    facebookUserId: facebookUserId,
  };
  const user = await findOne(users, query);
  res.json(user);
});

module.exports = router;
```

If you want to use the param instead `/:facebookUserId` like in your original code, you'll need to change the endpoint call to be like so
`http://xxx/api/users/10213594301678639`

Answer (score 0):

doing the following to capture query param works:

```
router.get(':facebookUserId?' ... (req, res) => { 
 ... 
 const facebookUserId = req.query.facebookUserId; 
 ... 
});
```